# Проблема при вычислении хэша

Tags: c#, .net, кодировка, хеширование, sha

Вычисляю HMAC SHA1, алгоритм следующий:

```
    public static string Encode(string input, string key)
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

        using (var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)))
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                return hmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream).Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + String.Format("{0:X2}", e), s => s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Хэш считается, но если в сообщении присутствуют символы \" (например объектов сериализованных в json) то хэш вычисляется неправильно. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Пример вычисления хэшей:
Сообщение hello, ключ hello. Мой код выдает результат
**9ADE18F3E0EE81A5343F4A005F795DBAF9CEEFD8**, код какого нибудь онлайн сервиса выдает точно такой же хэш. 
Сообщение hello\", ключ hello. Мой код выдает **89E81E2037598EFAB46FF882661EECD3FF409D73**
Какой нибудь онлайн сервис **c24001586dffaa049e74893babf11625995bd570**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот это HMAC от строки `hello"`, которая в c# записывается так `"hello\""`:

```
89e81e2037598efab46ff882661eecd3ff409d73
```

А это HMAC от строки `hello\"`, которая в c# записывается так `"hello\\\""`:

```
c24001586dffaa049e74893babf11625995bd570
```

Онлайн сервисы воспринимают строку в чистом виде, не обрабатывая экранирующие символы.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь все понятно.